# Copying ArrayList to Hashmap and resetting Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to add an ArrayList to a HashMap, and I am referencing the ArrayList to a different object later.

But when I change the contents of the ArrayList, it is reflected in the HashMap value too

Example:

```
       HashMap<Interger, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

       List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
       list1.add("cat");
       map.put(1, list1); 

       list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

       list1.add("dog");
       map.put(2, list1);
```

Now the map has only the "dog" entry in it, It does have the "cat" entry.

I don't want to create an ArrayList with a new name like list2 to hold the "dog" entry.

I am using this in a loop, so I need to have only one ArrayList variable like...list1... and I want to put the data into HashMap, and go on with....

list1 = new ArrayList();
and store new values in it and put it to the HasnMap.

How do I correctly put values into HashMap by using only one ArrayList variable?

Comment: Use `clone()` or add a call to `new ArrayList<>(list1)` when you add it. As is, you are adding the same *reference*.

Comment: no. in your example the map contains `{1: ["cat"], 2: ["dog"]}` I suspect your actual code contains `list1.clear()`, or something equivalent

Comment: I have the similar code. But its not working.

Comment: `Interger` is not a standard Java type.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is impossible to declare the map as receiving an :`HashMAP<Integer,ArrayList<String>>` 
and putting a list argument to it : `map.put(1, list1)`, 
 Even if an Arraylist **is a** list, take look at **java generics** to anderstand why it is forbidden in all `generics`.

I tested your code, and even if you set a new instance to the variable : `list1`, 
the instance added before to the `map` will not be removed from it :

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   list1.add("cat");
   map.put(1, list1); 

   list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

   list1.add("dog");
   map.put(2, list1);
   System.out.println(map.get(1).get(0)+" "+map.get(2).get(0));
```

will return : `cat dog'